# Does this interface require a Null modem cable?

Tags: serial-port

I[image] am enclosing here the drawing of the RS-232 9 pin connection cable to link a XT2000i Blood analyser to a host PC. Is this just any serial port cable or a Null modem cable ?

Thanks. Chak.

Since @JTON said in the answer that other pins are not swapped, i am enclosing image of which pins are in use.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It only has the Rx and Tx pins swapped so putting a null modem adapter in there will not match it exactly.  Usually they also have DTR/DSR and RTS/CTS swapped.  It depends if the device actually uses those pins.

To be safe about reliability, I'd probably make a cable exactly to specs.  Just get a make your own cable kit and all you have to do is pop the pins in.

Answer (score 1):

Since the lines is crossed it is a null-modem cable.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a variation of the null modem cable shown here:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_modem

basically you are crossing the send-data / receive-date
I would start with a null-modem cable